# Adding percentage to a number

Tags: c

I'm trying to add tax to a number and after compiling the tax is not included in the addition to the number.

I have tried int or float also this %f but it seems it is not making the math after compiling.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{

 float setprice, price, tax;

 printf("enter price in dollars : \n");
 scanf("%f", &price);


 printf("Enter the tax: \n");
 scanf("%f", &tax);

 setprice=(price*tax)+price;
 printf("total = %f\n", price);



    return 0;
}
```

After entering the code on IDE this is the output.

```
enter price in dollars :                                                     
100                                                                          
Enter the tax:                                                               
50                                                                           
total = 100.000000
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I don't know C# but this does look like C or C++. Please use the correct tag accordingly.

Comment: I am also flagging for closure as typo, because you wrote `printf("total = %f\n", price);` where you probably meant `printf("total = %f\n", setprice);`.

Comment: @uneven_mark hey thanks mate, I was able to resolve this. so what I did was simply modify setprice=(price+tax); printf("total = %f\n", setprice); . Now im able to calculate tax and number and no errors in output. Thank you man and i'll be sure to assign the correct tag.

Comment: I don't know of a printf() function in C#.  Is this C or C++ ?

Comment: `printf("total = %f\n", price);` instead of `printf("total = %f\n", setprice);` is one of those *...doah....* moments -- we've all been there. [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is adding `"%"` to tax variable. when you enter 50 it should be like 50%.

Then do this

```
tax = tax / 100
setprice = (price * tax) + price;
printf("total = %f\n", setprice);
```

or you can try this

```
setprice = (price * (tax / 100)) + price;
printf("total = %f\n", setprice);
```

these answers will work!